# Create MVC.Net filter and htmlhelper library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use MVC.net alot, and I made some functionality (or found it on internet) which I use in every project (custom authentication filterattribute, ImageActionlink html helper etc). Is it possible to create a "class" library with these filters and htmlhelpers etc? So I could import them in every project.

And how would you do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a reusable class library. Simply add a new project of type [Class Library](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s16p1.html) to your solution and include the helper classes inside. Then you can reference the compiled assembly in other projects in order to reuse the functionality.